# Node.js bot does not always send image

Tags: node.js, bots, telegram

Node telegram bot does not send image to some users. I use the following code, which seems to be quite standard:

```
bot.onText(/text/, (msg, match) => {
  // From file path
  const chatID = msg.chat.id;
  const photo = `http://i.imgur.com/Hvr4CJX.png`;
  bot.sendPhoto(chatID, photo, {
    caption: "caption"
  });
```

Can it be some security thing, or that particular devices do not receive images, or maybe connection speed?

I tried hosting the image on github and link there, but the issue remains.

Answer (score 0):

There is an open bug [here](https://github.com/yagop/node-telegram-bot-api/issues/267) which may be your issue.

The `.sendPhoto()` method assumes that the image path is always available. Knowing the stability of imgur servers (well lack of stability), that image is not going to be available for every request. I would put the file on the server, read it with an `fs` readStream (this way we always have access to it), then send the photo.

Comment: Doesn't work. Some users are still not receiving any images on request, while others are unaffected and the behaviour seems to be similar to when image was loaded from url

Comment: @KristianVybiral So you tried to host the image locally on the same server which held the script and some users are still not getting it?

Comment: That's right. Some users are, but others are not. I don't really see any pattern.